# dmesg - how to make boot sequence faster

Tags: 12.10, boot, dmesg

My system used to boot pretty fast when I first installed ubuntu almost one year ago, but now takes a lot more.

I used dmesg to see if I could find anything and there seems to be a 35 second gap between entries, but I don't know what I'm supposed to do to fix that.

Part of my dmesg output is here:

```
[    1.940788] Registered led device: mmc0::
[    1.970100] mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:05:00.1] using DMA
[    1.970152] sdhci-pci 0000:05:00.2: SDHCI controller found [197b:2391] (rev 90)
[    1.970181] sdhci-pci 0000:05:00.2: Refusing to bind to secondary interface.
[    2.003943] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=0315
[    2.003953] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
[    2.003959] usb 2-1.6: Product: BisonCam, NB Pro
[    2.003964] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: BISON Corporation
[    2.673778] EXT3-fs (loop0): recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    2.673781] EXT3-fs (loop0): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    9.178331] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[    9.214017] EXT3-fs (loop0): recovery complete
[    9.214020] EXT3-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
[   44.393685] Adding 262140k swap on /host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:262140k 
[   44.412667] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   44.441301] EXT3-fs (loop0): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
[   44.484151] EXT3-fs (loop0): using internal journal
[   44.518587] udevd[509]: starting version 175
```

And I also have posted the complete file [here](http://anpel.dimiourgiasite.gr/dmesg)

How can I make my boot sequence faster?

---------- EDIT ------

I also have installed bootchart

The image output is here:

http://anpel.dimiourgiasite.gr/ubuntu-quantal.png

And the log files that come with it are here:

http://anpel.dimiourgiasite.gr/ubuntu-quantal.tgz

Please note that my machine dual boots (it always has, even when it did boot quickly) and that I have installed Ubuntu using the windows ubuntu installer.

Comment: `dmesg` is irrelevant.  You will want to use the `bootchart` package to see what is running and for how long during boot.

Comment: Install `bootchart` to identify the bottleneck. Why are you using a loop device - the ext3 filesystem?

Comment: @TerryWang & psusi : I have edited the question. I am not good with this kind of stuff, I thougt dmesg was more relevant..

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this? BTW, I would use ext4 and something else but Wubi.

Comment: @Braiam I now use ext4 too, I reinstalled everything when I got an ssd

Comment: Ok, that means that this question right now is obsolete?

Comment: @Braiam Exactly, since I dont even use that install anymore. Should I delete it?