# Boot time is more than one minute with ext3 FS recovery everytime

Tags: boot, wubi, ext3

It takes more than a minute for Ubuntu to boot up on my new laptop. I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 installed using Wubi.

From dmesg, I see the following:

```
[    2.934384] EXT3-fs (loop0): recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    2.934387] EXT3-fs (loop0): write access will be enabled during recovery
[   23.804784] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[   23.871524] EXT3-fs (loop0): recovery complete
[   23.871526] EXT3-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
[   45.069369] Adding 262140k swap on /host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:262140k
```

Note the big time gap between the entries. You might ask whether I put my computer to a unclean shutdown because of the filesystem recovery, but I just shut it down gracefully using the system menu.

How can I improve the boot time?

Comment: Describe how you are shutting the system down.  If you are not going through a clean shutdown, you will get disk cleanup on boot.

Comment: `loop0` device? Are you using Wubi? At least this is not a regular hard disk installation.

Comment: I use Settings->Shut down...I normally close all the applications before shutting down my system but not always.But this happens everytime I boot.What is it that I must ideally do ?

Comment: Yes,I used Wubi installer to get Ubuntu on my windows 7.

Comment: wubi is slower as it operates in virtual environment.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/233438/dmesg-how-to-make-boot-sequence-faster?rq=1 ..

Comment: However,I did not see a solution in that post.

Comment: @Pal Consider editing your comments rather than posting new ones over and over again. Also, you should edit your question with this relevant information. I've done this for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

That's not normal for Wubi. Mine takes about 4 seconds to load where yours is taking 20.

The key is that your filesystem is marked as corrupted. And if it's doing that every time then whatever `fsck` is doing is not fixing the problem. So you could `fsck` it from a live CD and see if it provides any decent output. Or try running `chkdsk /f` from Windows - as there could be some `NTFS` corruption as well. Or try reinstalling.

Here's my output for the equivalent operations - and ignore the swap as it uses a partition (also my `root.disk` is `ext4` as it was installed via the `ISO` but that shouldn't make any difference to the time required to mount it):

```
[    2.113178] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 5
[    4.450760] EXT4-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    7.650487] Adding 4300796k swap on /dev/sda7.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4300796k 
[    8.583207] EXT4-fs (loop0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    9.025386] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```